# Problem with Git after changing the default theme

Tags: bash

After changing the default theme in Bash I get these two lines:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'.
bash: command substitution: line 1: `scm_prompt_info)'
```

And it is uncomfortable, because when I use any command I get those two lines, so I wanted to know how to solve this, thank you if you can help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGFDc.png)

Comment: You almost certainly have a typo in your `$PS1` setting or similar.

Comment: What does `echo $PS` give?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @Jan `printf %q "$PS1"` would be more informative.